# Netsuite SDF Deploy Error - Gateway Time-Out

Tags: javascript, eclipse, netsuite, suitescript, suitecloud

I am currently trying to setp-up an SDF Project for my NetSuite account. I've worked through a number of validation/deploy errors but now when I deploy it runs for about 10 minutes and then gives this error:

The remote server returned an error:

https://5115829-sb1.app.netsuite.com:443/app/suiteapp/devframework/ideinstallhandler.nl - Gateway Time-out

I've enabled SDF feature in my account and have attached a custom SDF developer role to my user with the SuiteApp deployment, and Find Transaction permissions enabled. I'm using Eclipse for MacOS.

Anyone else have this issue?

Could my project be too big that it takes too long to deploy?

Comment: I experienced the same error when trying to upload node_modules folder to test using those dependencies in Netsuite account. The deployment lasts for more than 10 minutes and the log registers the fail when Validating the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my project was too large. I had to remove a few custom objects so it could deploy before timing out (which I think is 10 minutes).